# Watermark in Passbook

Tags: passwords, watermark, passbook

Is it possible to add a watermark in my Passbook passes and does anyone of you know how to do it?
I really need it and I do not know how to do it.

Thank you very much to all!

Comment: you can embed whatever watermark you like into the pass images, but there is no way to add anything to the pass background, or to overlay the pass with an image.  Why is a watermark so important for you? Perhaps there is another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I used a background.png instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a watermark to passbook.

In the case of an Event Ticket you can add a background image and with it your watermark if you like but you can't do the same to the other types of passes (Boarding Pass, Coupon, Generic).

My recommendation is that you use the backFields and add there some kind of text communicating your brand.

Comment: Table 3.1 in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html) really helped me but it was @Immendes comment that got me to look for it!